# Problem loading model state dictionary of model checkpoint

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to load an checkpoint but I am getting an error message.
How I save and load the checkpoint:

1. saving

```
torch.save({'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(), 'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict()}, chkpt_path)
```

2. loading

```
chkpt = torch.load(chkpt_path, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
net.load_state_dict(chkpt['model_state_dict'])
```

I am getting the following error multiple times for all my layers after executing the following line "net.load_state_dict(chkpt['model_state_dict'])" :
`While copying the parameter named "residual_layer.residual_block ...", whose dimensions in the model are torch.Size([1, 524, 32, 2]) and whose dimensions in the checkpoint are torch.Size([1, 524, 32, 2]), an exception occurred : ('unsupported operation: more than one element of the written-to tensor refers to a single memory location. Please clone() the tensor before performing the operation.',).`

How to use the clone() function to load the checkpoint dictionary correctly?
I trained the model on cpu and want to do the inference also on cpu.

I tried to add the clone function to the load_state_dict() but without success ...

Comment: Voting to close. This needs an [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your model. You have a tensor somewhere in your model that uses the same memory for multiple values, and something is trying to write to it.

E.g. I can use `expand` to create a tensor where multiple rows occupy the same memory, and where modifying one value actually changes two values:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1,2,3]).expand( (2,3) )
>>> x
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]])
>>> x[0,0]
tensor(1)
>>> x[0,0] = 99
>>> x
tensor([[99,  2,  3],
        [99,  2,  3]])
>>>
```

You have something like that somewhere in your model, and so I suppose the checkpoint loading code doesn't know how to handle it, but check the stack trace to see for sure. It's asking you to clone the offending tensor (in your model). e.g. `x = x.clone()`

I can change the above code adding `clone` to not get the repeated 99's

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1,2,3]).expand( (2,3) ).clone()
>>> x[0,0]=99
>>> x
tensor([[99,  2,  3],
        [ 1,  2,  3]])
```

Your problem is probably not `expand` specifically, there are many pytorch functions that can lead to non-contiguous tensors. FYI instead of `.clone()` you could also use `.contiguous()`

Also, here would be an example of doing an in-place modification of the above tensor, reproducing your error message. Again there are many ways to get such memory-sharing tensors and many ways to in-place modify them:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1,2,3]).expand( (2,3) )
>>> x.mul_(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: unsupported operation: more than one element of the written-to tensor refers to a single memory location. Please clone() the tensor before performing the operation.
```

Answer (score 0):

my assumption is that you're using a DataParallel to train your model.
if you have a model with a parameter named 'weight', when using DataParallel, the key in the state dictionary will be 'module.weight'.
and DataParallel automatically wraps the model with a module that has this prefix.

so try:

```
if 'module.' in list(chkpt['model_state_dict'].keys())[0]:
new_state_dict = {}
for key, value in chkpt['model_state_dict'].items():
    new_key = key.replace('module.', '')
    new_state_dict[new_key] = value
chkpt['model_state_dict'] = new_state_dict
```

before `net.load_state_dict(chkpt['model_state_dict'])`.